# Error message on HTML 5 not showing

Tags: angularjs, html, spring

I am using spring boot and angularjs to display error messages on my html page. I am using HTML 5. However, it won't display anything on my page. And I really don't know why. I have included my code below, so that you can have a look at it.

```
<form id="save" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-controller="addEmployee">
   <h4>Add a new employee</h4>
   <label for="fname">First Name:</label> <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="fname" id="fname"/> 
   <div class="help-block" ng-messages="save.fname.$error" ng-show="save.fname.$touched">
      <div ng-messages="save.fname.$error" ng-show="save.fname.$touched">
         <div ng-message="required"> You forgot to enter your first name. </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Give your form a name....<form name="save" id="save" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-controller="addEmployee">

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add required

try like this

```
 <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="fname" id="fname" required />
```

And also provide name to your form instead of id

Like this

```
<form name="save" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-controller="addEmployee">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the following changes:

1. Give name to your form
2. Add novalidate attribute to form
3. Add required attribute to the input field

`<form name="save" id="save" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-controller="addEmployee" novalidate>`

`<h4>Add a new employee</h4>
   <label for="fname">First Name:</label> <input type="text" name="fname" ng-model="fname" id="fname" required/> 
   <div class="help-block" ng-messages="save.fname.$error" ng-show="save.fname.$touched">
      <div ng-messages="save.fname.$error" ng-show="save.fname.$touched">
         <div ng-message="required"> You forgot to enter your first name. </div>
      </div>
   </div>`

`</form>`